# Query which will perform better than recursive cte

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a data around 5 million records, the following is the sample data which will relates to it

```
if object_id('tempdb..#Table1') is not null
drop TABLE #Table1
CREATE TABLE #Table1
    ([Hierarchy_No] varchar(8), [sales] int)
;

INSERT INTO #Table1
    ([Hierarchy_No], [sales])
VALUES
    ('1-1.1.1.', 100),
    ('1-1.1.2.', 200),
    ('1-1.2.1', 300),
    ('1-1.2.1', 400),
    ('1-2.1.1.', 500),
    ('1-2.1.2.', 600),
    ('1-2.2.1', 700),
    ('1-2.2.1', 800)
;
```

we have used recursive cte to achieve the following result.

```
Hierarchy_No    sales
1-1.            1000
1-2.            2600
1-1.1.          300
1-1.2.          700
1-2.1.          1100
1-2.2.          1500
1-1.1.1.        100
1-1.1.2.        200
1-1.2.1         300
1-1.2.1         400
1-2.1.1.        500
1-2.1.2.        600
1-2.2.1.        700
1-2.2.1.        800
```

To achieve results for 1-1. we have to add sales of `1-1.1.1.+1-1.1.2.+1-1.2.1.+1-1-2.1.` i.e is 1000.
is there any way to achieve the results other than recursive cte? Kindly help.

Comment: Depends - is the hierarchy always based on exactly 3 levels (and assuming the trailing `.` is irrelevant)?

Comment: No it can be more than 3. At max i will have 10 levels. Thanks!

Comment: `1-1.` is not in your sample data, how do you select it?

Comment: Can you show the recursive cte you have right now, So that we will have something to compare to?

Comment: @HoneyBadger this is my sample data and the provided data is for one particular period

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that comment. Your input data is all 4 numbers, with different separators, how do you get a value with 2 numbers? Probably a related question: How is the Hierarchy defined, what is the parent, what is the child?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do it (still using a recursive cte, but since you didn't share yours, I have no idea if that's going to be a better one):

```
;WITH RCTE AS
(
    SELECT  [Hierarchy_No],
            CHARINDEX('.', [Hierarchy_No]) As DotPosition,
            [sales]
    FROM  #Table1
    UNION ALL

    SELECT  [Hierarchy_No],
            CHARINDEX('.', [Hierarchy_No], DotPosition + 1),
            [sales]
    FROM RCTE
    WHERE DotPosition > 0 AND DotPosition < LEN([Hierarchy_No]) - 1
)

SELECT LEFT([Hierarchy_No], DotPosition) As Hierarchy, SUM([sales]) As Total_Sales
FROM RCTE 
GROUP BY LEFT([Hierarchy_No], DotPosition)
```

I've also tried using a numbers table instead of a recursive cte, but all my attempts where proven less effective for this sample data.

```
SELECT  LEFT ([Hierarchy_No], Number) As Hierarchy,
        SUM(sales)
FROM  #Table1
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT Number 
    FROM Tally 
    WHERE Number <= 8 -- (the maximum length of the `[Hierarchy_No]` column)
)
Tally ON SUBSTRING([Hierarchy_No], Number, 1) = '.'
GROUP BY LEFT ([Hierarchy_No], Number) 
ORDER BY Hierarchy
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way using [hierarchyid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/hierarchyid-data-type-method-reference?view=sql-server-2017) data type

```
select
    stuff(replace(replace(res.GetAncestor(n).ToString(), '.', '-'), '/', '.'), 1, 1, '')
    , sum(sales)
from (
    select
        *, res = cast('/' + replace(replace(Hierarchy_No, '.', '/'), '-', '.') as hierarchyid)

    from
        #Table1 c
        join (values (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9)) t(n) 
            on len(Hierarchy_No) - len(replace(Hierarchy_No, '.', '')) > t.n
) t
group by res.GetAncestor(n).ToString()
```

Notes:

1. `Hierarchy_No` must be numeric as in your example. Only one non numeric character can be handled by converting it to `.`
2. There's no other column that identifies that last two `Hierarchy_No` are different. So they are grouped in the output. List it in group by statement if you have such a column

Answer (score 0):

This solutions turns each hierarchy_no into rows of every character to get the required hierarchies:

```
select x.HierarchyCheck as [Hierarchy_No], sum(t1.sales) as [sales]
from #table1 t1
inner join (
    SELECT  distinct     IIF(SUBSTRING([Hierarchy_No],Number,1) = '.', LEFT([Hierarchy_No], number), '') as HierarchyCheck
    FROM #Table1
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT DISTINCT number FROM master..spt_values WHERE number > 0 AND number <= LEN([Hierarchy_No]))V ) as x on t1.Hierarchy_No like x.HierarchyCheck + '%'  and right(x.HierarchyCheck, 1) ='.'
group by x.HierarchyCheck
UNION
select T1.Hierarchy_No as [Hierarchy_No], t1.sales as [sales]
from #table1 t1
WHERE RIGHT(T1.Hierarchy_No,1)<>'.'
```